# daterangepicker dropdown won't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, daterangepicker

[image]

Just like the picture implies,while using firefox,dropdown won't show.Neither will google chrome.
Here is the set of daterangepicker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        //set end time
        $('#id_end_time').daterangepicker({
        "timePicker": true,
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "timePickerIncrement": 1,
        "autoApply": true,
        "format": 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        });
      });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        //set start time
        $('#id_start_time').daterangepicker({
        "timePicker": true,
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "timePickerIncrement": 1,
        "autoApply": true,
        "format": 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: put your jquery code in `$( document ).ready(function() {});`

Comment: any exception in console..?? Merge both the function in to single  $(function (){...});

Comment: allow me to correct,dropdown is able to show in google chrome.

Comment: unfortunately,console show nothing at all